# ASP.NET Core ViewComponent Invocation: InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, json.net

Here is what I have

I have a view component as

```
public class TestViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
     public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int param1, int param2)
     {
         return Content(param1.ToString() + param2);
     }
}
```

And a controller as

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
     private Dictionary<string, object> _dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

     public IActionResult Index()
     {
         _dict = new Dictionary<string, object>() { ["param1"] = 100, ["param2"] = 200 };
         return ViewComponent("Test", _dict)
     }

     public IActionResult Index1()
     {
         var obj = new { param1 = 100, param2 = 200 };
         var objString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
         _dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(objString);
         return ViewComponent("Test", _dict);
     }
 }
```

When I call the first `Index` action everything is good. It works as expected but when I call the `Index1` action I get an error with the following stack trace

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Int32'.
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentInvoker.<InvokeAsyncCore>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentHelper.<InvokeCoreAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ViewComponentResultExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
```

It seems there is some issue after the Deserialization. The exception is thrown even before the `InvokeAsync` method of the view component is called. 
I have been stuck on this for a while. Any help will be really appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty much telling what's happening here. The actual `object`s in the deserialized dictionary are `Int64`s, which the arguments expected by the `ViewComponent` are `Int32` (also called  `int` in C#).

Comment: can I change the behaviour of the deserialize method to not change numbers to Int64 by default and have int32 instead ?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `object` in `DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(...)` to `int`?